# how to make executable file of php with js,css and images connected to sql database

Tags: php

I have PHP files, CSS, JS and images which are connected to an SQL database via  XAMPP on a local host. How to compile these as one and run it as an executable file? In that database, I have plenty of tables which are used for getting the IDs of the inputs from input fields. I have used this software, ZZEE  PhpExe 2.6.1 but the contents of the CSS and JS did not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you master the object oriented php to use php-gtk, gtk is a library used for applications desktop.

If I'm not mistaken, Firefox and Chrome have resources paarafazer it natively.

but in my opinion, try using PHP Desktop Chromium.
https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop-chromium/